# Cassandra is not working on server - ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused)'

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra

I purchased a server(Singapore zone, 512 MB RAM) I tried to setup single node cluster in that server. I followed from this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-cassandra-and-run-a-single-node-cluster-on-ubuntu-14-04) when I checked `$ sudo service Cassandra status` It was showing

> nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused)'.

I tried to resolve using this [stackoverflow](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/cassandra/3.10/apache-cassandra-3.10-bin.tar.gz) link still it showing same error. Then I tried to setup it using tar file form this [apache official](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/getting_started/installing.html#installation-from-binary-tarball-files) when I checked with `$ ./nodetool status`
Still I am getting same issue.

Note:- With local machine it is working fine.

I am unable to figure out why i am getting problem with server.
I think "**Nodes seem to freeze after some period of time**" because I checked that after starting node it is killed. I tried to get some idea from this [link](http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/troubleshooting/trblshootNodeFreeze_r.html?hl=killed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Review the system.log and debug.log.

I'm pretty sure that Cassandra node needs more than 512mb RAM to run.

Here, the recommendation is 4gb minimum:

https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraHardware

Comment: Yes SIr I just resolved it with the help of 

http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/troubleshooting/trblshootNodeFreeze_r.html?hl=killed

Actually Because Cassandra has multiple replicas and transparent failover, it is preferable for a replica to be killed immediately when memory is low rather than go into swap. I took 4GB RAM Server and issues has been resolved. 
thanks

Comment: i followed using this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-a-multi-node-cluster-database-with-cassandra-on-ubuntu-14-04  and i have two server with 4gb ram i checked both are runing cassendra . i have changed firewall but  when i checked nodetool status on both server but it is showing the corresponding server ip only .

Comment: Do you have ports 7000 and 9042 opened in your security group? Are the nodes configured with same cluster name/seeds list?

Comment: Still it is creating same error. i have 4GB RAM.
First It was showing "active (running) " status . when I checked after few second back it was showing "active (exited)"

Comment: When i checked I got this error :

Cannot start node if snitch's data center (datacenter1) differs from previous data center (dc1). Please fix the snitch configuration, decommission and rebootstrap this node or use the flag -Dcassandra.ignore_dc=true.

Comment: if you recreated the node, remove all contents of data directory, including system directory.

Comment: thanks a lot I used " rm -rf /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/*" and resolved it. I request to you please provide me good link for creating multiple cassandra node for GossipFilePropertySnitch . i followed digital ocean document but at some point i am getting problem specially in firewall, I am newbie sir.

Comment: You can start with it: http://highscalability.com/blog/2016/8/1/how-to-setup-a-highly-available-multi-az-cassandra-cluster-o.html Just diregard the snitching parts, or use ec2snitch if you already in AWS.